# how to fix ChakraCore NuGet package error?

Tags: visual-studio, react-native, nuget, xamarin-studio, chakracore

When initializing a new React Native Windows WPF project, this error happens:

`NuGet Package restore failed for project Native: Unable to find version '1.4.1-preview-00010-42060' of package 'Microsoft.ChakraCore'.
https://www.myget.org/F/chakracore-preview/api/v3/index.json: Package 'Microsoft.ChakraCore.1.4.1-preview-00010-42060' is not found on source 'https://www.myget.org/F/chakracore-preview/api/v3/index.json'.
https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Package 'Microsoft.ChakraCore.1.4.1-preview-00010-42060' is not found on source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'.`

If I create a standalone project and add the same NuGet package reference, I get the same error -- even on Xamarin Studio Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the project was referencing the "preview" feed on myget.org, instead of the official release feed on nuget.org. In the NuGet.Config file(s) in your project, remove line that references the preview feed that looks like this:

`<add key="ChakraCore" value="https://www.myget.org/F/chakracore-preview/api/v3/index.json" />`

In the Visual Studio 2015 (or Xamarin/Visual Studio Mac) project, right-click on the project and select Manage NuGet References. From there, you can click on the Updates tab, select ChakraCore from the list, and click "Update". This should update the packages.config and other files for you. Note that if you had the project open while editing the config files you'll need to close and re-open the project to get the new settings to take hold. In some cases, the upgrade may leave behind the reference to the previous 1.4.1-preview package and you'll need to hand-edit the csproj file to get rid of it.

If you need to make this change without Visual/Xamarin Studio, you just have to edit a few text files. In the packages.config (in Visual Studio 2015), change the line referencing the 1.4.1-preview version to the latest release (1.5.2 as of this writing):

`<package id="Microsoft.ChakraCore" version="1.4.1-preview-00010-42060" targetFramework="net46" developmentDependency="true" />`

becomes

`<package id="Microsoft.ChakraCore" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net46" developmentDependency="true" />`

In your project's csproj file:
`<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\packages\Microsoft.ChakraCore.1.4.1\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.ChakraCore.props" Condition="Exists('$(SolutionDir)\packages\Microsoft.ChakraCore.1.4.1\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.ChakraCore.props')" />`

becomes

`<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\packages\Microsoft.ChakraCore.1.5.2\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.ChakraCore.props" Condition="Exists('$(SolutionDir)\packages\Microsoft.ChakraCore.1.5.2\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.ChakraCore.props')" />`

and

`<Error Condition="!Exists('$(SolutionDir)\packages\Microsoft.ChakraCore.1.4.1\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.ChakraCore.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '$(SolutionDir)\packages\Microsoft.ChakraCore.1.4.1\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.ChakraCore.props'))" />`

becomes

`<Error Condition="!Exists('$(SolutionDir)\packages\Microsoft.ChakraCore.1.5.2\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.ChakraCore.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '$(SolutionDir)\packages\Microsoft.ChakraCore.1.5.2\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.ChakraCore.props'))" />`

Generally speaking, don't reference preview packages from myget.org in production projects or project templates others will use. They can be removed at any time, and security updates may not be published there with the same regularity as official channels.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the preview Microsoft.ChakraCore NuGet package was removed from the [MyGet feed](https://www.myget.org/feed/chakracore-preview/package/nuget/Microsoft.ChakraCore).

The main NuGet.org site only has stable releases for the [Microsoft.ChakraCore NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ChakraCore/).

So you are left with editing any references to the package and using a published version. Microsoft.ChakraCore version 1.4.4 should work.

There is also an [open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-windows/issues/1154) about this on the React native GitHub site.